# Access to server side pages remotely

Tags: asp.net, windows, security

I have a website running IIS 8.5 on windows 2012r2 with the application written in ASP.NET and this hacker is able to access backend pages, steal sessions and somehow post to them remotely.

We have a social network website with profiles, messages, walls etc and he is able to get around all backend security somehow. I have attempted everything to lock him out. My web config has these settings. But none of this works. My website is SSL and require SSL is enabled.

`<add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"/> <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff"/> <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY"/> <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block"/>`

I am at my wits end here. What do I do?

I have tried everything I can think of I am out of ideas here.

Comment: Security questions like this would require a book like response, and we would need ALL details of the server setup. For starters, is FTP enabled? Perhaps a poor and easy FTP password exists for the site, and the person not hacking the asp.net site, but is in fact using FTP and has that password. I would turn off FTP for starters. However, this is WAY WAY beyond a simple Q+A forum like Stack Overflow. Not sure what is worse, not having proper asp.net skills, or thinking that such a simple answer can be hand on a Q+A forum like SO. (you are clearly in over your head here).

Comment: The server is behind a firewall in a secured NOC so that is not the issue. The firewall blocks all ip's that are not mine to FTP services.

Comment: Perhaps your files are infected and the entire server is compromised from within. Maybe you have a faulty / leaky fileuploader, and the attacker is simply using something they have uploaded previously.